# Redis cache .net core sample with GCP memorystore

Tags: .net-core, redis, sample, google-cloud-memorystore

Does anyone have .Net core sample of using GCP Memorystore Redis instance. What libraries one need to use mainly for key-value kind of store.

Comment: Google Cloud Platform supports installing client libraries for the Memorystore to connect to Redis APIs with C#/.NET Core as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/libraries#client-libraries-install-csharp). You can refer to [this document](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/using-memorystore-for-redis-as-a-leaderboard) to find some samples in C#/.NET Core.
 
Additionally, could you please add some more information to the question, specifically what you are trying to do, so that we can understand the question better and provide a better response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** - I used Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis library to connect and do the operations. The only caveat is that it doesn't have the RemoveAll support i.e. removing or clearing all the keys.

Answer (score 0):

I am having similar issue like mahesh posted.

I check the library recommend by Google .net core. but could not find the method how to set TTL.

is their an sample available for Add, read, remove operation with net with library.

Regards
Samir